# Node.js harmony: How to yield elasticsearch.js calls (using koa)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, generator, yield, koa

After an hour of trying various syntaxes and npm modules:

How would I achieve yielding a call to the elasticsearch client? I'm looking at something like this:

```
var res = yield *client.get({
  index: index,
  type: type,
  id: id,
  ignore: [404]
})
```

I have no idea what res should or would be, but I need to know if the document was found/exists.

Edit: Got it working with `require('thunkify-wrap').genify(client.get)`.
Now both `yield client.get({...})` AND `yield *client.get({...})` works. Beats me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way could be wrapping around the Elasticsearch client with [thunkify](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-thunkify). This might do it:

```
var thunkify = require('thunkify');
var get = thunkify(client.get);

var res = yield get({ ... });
```

Comment: I think I tried that and got `illegal invocation` error. Maybe have to do `get.bind(client)`... Will test this.